# Method not found when I use bitcoin-cli to generate blocks under regtest mode

Tags: bitcoin-cli, command-line-options

[image]

As the picture shows,I am really confuesd.

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core are you using?

Answer (score 7):

For the upcoming Bitcoin Core 0.18 release, the `generate` command has been deprecated and its functionality disabled. For the following major release, 0.19.0, the `generate` command has been removed entirely. This removal is already in the master branch of Bitcoin Core's source code. If you have built that branch from source, then the `generate` command does not exist.

Use `generatetoaddress` instead.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot ! Next time I'll search more carefully~Thank you for your patience.